# How do I render an image with GDI in C?

Tags: c, windows, user-interface, gdi

Very simple question: how do I render a png image with GDI in C (including its transparencies)?

Comment: You'd probably be better off if you can use GDI+

Comment: @dreamlax yea, you're probably right. ill go with gdi+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with GDI+ instead of GDI.